# SQLAlchemy successfully installed, but I still get error ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm

I am trying run code which is using SQLAlchemy. I use PyCharm with virtual environment. I don't have this problem few weeks ago and now I don't know what is wrong.

What I have tried:

1.) deleting venv folder from project, and set new virtual interpreter.
Didn't help, I clicked on Install package SQLAlchemy, get notification that package was successfully installed, but it is still underlined and if I try to run, I get error **ModuleNotFound...**
[SQLAlchemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucUSN.png)

2.) trying to install it from Terminal in PyCharm

```
(venv) cipisek@macbookair Starting+Files+-+cafe-api-start % pip3 install SQLAlchemy
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.4.41)
```

After this, still same problem. [SQLAlchemy2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7c5l.png)

3.) completely new project, with new virtual environment... same problem :/

4.) importing only SQLAlchemy instead `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy` [import SQLAlchemy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Av3.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cipisek/PycharmProjects/Starting+Files+-+cafe-api-start/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SQLAlchemy'
```

If I tried to check packages which are installed in my environment, the SQLAlchemy is there. I don't understand why it is not working. [List of installed packeges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoUuu.png) Could someone help me please?

I have found similar problems on this forum, but there aren't any solutions which solve my problem.

Comment: use like this  -> import sqlalchemy

Comment: @anwarshawn same problem :/

Comment: remove the line from flask_sqlalchemy import sqlalchemy
just put import sqlalchemy

Comment: @anwarshawn I have tried it. I have also edited my post with this solution. Check point 4.

Comment: try with this
pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
and  make the import like this 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

Comment: @anwarshawn thank you for your help. Solution from Nero solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete and install again sqlAlchemy via terminal:

```
pip uninstall SQLAlchemy
pip install SQLAlchemy
```

Or upgrade it:

```
pip install SQLAlchemy --upgrade
```

Comment: You are awesome, thank you :) Uninstalling and install package again solves my problem. I didn't try it, because I thought if I create new project with new environment it is clean.